# I need to design below image table from html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-table

[image: sample image]

I need to make an html table according to the table structure from the image above. I tried many ways but I can't do it.

Please help me create the Html table.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes for HTML table elements.

Comment: `I tried many ways`: please show us what you tried and we can see if you're on the right track.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using a `colspan` on a header cell to have it take up the width of multiple cells, and then a `rowspan` on cells to have it expand vertically to multiple rows.

This gets you like 90% of the way to what your image shows.  The vertical/rotated text is possible, but not what this question was about here so I didn't do that part.

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,th {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
th {
  background: #CCC;
}
.blank {
  background: #FFF;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" class="blank"></th>
      <th colspan="8">Attribute Name 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" class="blank"></th>
      <th colspan="2">Attribute 1 Value 1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attribute 1 Value 2</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attribute 1 Value 3</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attribute 1 Value 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="32" class="vertical-text">Attribute Name</th>
      <th rowspan="4" class="vertical-text">Attribute 2 Value 1</th>
      <th>Price Category 1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" class="vertical-text">Attribute 2 Value 2</th>
      <th>Price Category 1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" class="vertical-text">Attribute 2 Value 3</th>
      <th>Price Category 1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" class="vertical-text">Attribute 2 Value 4</th>
      <th>Price Category 1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price Category 4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```